# For_each loop with for expression based on value in map

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Since the title is not descriptive enough let me introduce my problem.
I'm creating DRY module code for CDN that contains profile/endpoint/custom_domain.
Variable cdn_config would hold all necessary/optional parameters and these are created based on the for_each loop.

Variable looks like this:

```
variable "cdn_config" {
  profiles = {
    "profile_1" = {}
 }
 
 endpoints = {
    "endpoint_1" = {
       custom_domain = {
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Core of this module is working - in the means that it would create cdn_profile "profile_1" then cdn_endpoint "endpoint_1" will be created and assigned to this profile then cdn_custom_domain will be created and assigned to "endpoint_1" since it's the part of "endpoint_1" map.

Then I realize, what in case I want to create "cdn_custom_domain" only and specify resource ID manually?

I was thinking that adding the optional parameter "standalone" could help, so it would look like this:

```
variable "cdn_config" {
  profiles = {
    "profile_1" = {}
 }

 endpoints = {
    "endpoint_1" = {
       custom_domain = {
    }
  }
    "endpoint_standalone" = {
       custom_domain = {
         standalone = true
         cdn_endpoint_id = "xxxxx"
   }
  } 
 }
}
```

Having this "standalone" parameter eq true "endpoint_standalone" map should be totally ignored from looping in the azurerm_cdn_endpoint resource creation.

So far this direction is my only guess, clearly, it's not working - if I add "endpoint_standalone" it complains that not all required parameters are specified so it's surely finding it.

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "this" {

for_each = {for k in keys(var.cdn_config.endpoints) : k => var.cdn_config.endpoints[k] if lookup(var.cdn_config.endpoints[k],"standalone",null) != "true"}
```

I would be grateful if you have a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a bool type to a string type, so the logical comparison will always return false:

```
for_each = {for k in keys(var.cdn_config.endpoints) : k => var.cdn_config.endpoints[k] if lookup(var.cdn_config.endpoints[k],"standalone",null) != true }
```

While we are here, we can also improve this `for` expression:

```
for_each = { for endpoint, params in var.cdn_config.endpoints : endpoint => params if lookup(params.custom_domain, "standalone", null) != true }
```

Comment: Thank you Matt, that was really helpful, this is almost exactly what I was looking for. 
I modified it a little bit to allow not to create cdn_endpoint at all, for example if someone wants to create cdn_profile only, now it looks like this:

`for_each = lookup(var.cdn_config,"endpoints",null) != null ? { for endpoint, params in var.cdn_config.endpoints : endpoint => params if lookup(params.endpoint_custom_domain, "standalone", null) != true } : {}`

One last problem. now custom_domain must be specified or it will throw "This object does not have an attribute named "endpoint_custom_domain"

Comment: This could be problematic if I want to create "endpoint_1" with custom_domain and "endpoint_2" without it. 

In other resources and dynamic block I achieved it using `can` like this
`can(var.cdn_config.endpoints) == true ? var.cdn_config.profiles : {}`

Comment: @skwierczyk1 Yes without a `custom_domain` key this would be an issue, but your question has that key for all variable values. You would need a nested `lookup` if your actual values are different from the question in that way.

Comment: Matt,

You are great, indeed nested lookup solved my problem by looking for `custom_domain` and assigning empty map as default.

Thank you